# Move overload and destructor theory. Can someone please answer if I'm right?

Tags: c++, overloading, move

I'm trying to understand C++ move overloads and destructor calling right.
So I make test. My theory: The "foo" which returns foo_test() is created by move constructor, returned(as a copy ??) and then the "foo in" is destroyed. The returned "foo" from foo_test() is with move=overload assigned to "foo my" and then is destroyed. After that, "my" is printed and destroyed, because it goes out of scope.
Am I  close to correct answer ?

## Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
    int* p;
    int s;
public:
    foo(int in)
        :s{ in }, p{ new int[in] }{
        for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
            p[i] = i;
    }
    foo(foo&& a)
        :s{ a.s }, p{ a.p } {a.s = 0; a.p = nullptr; std::cout << "move cons was called" << std::endl; }
    foo& operator=(foo&& a) {
        delete[] p;
        p = a.p;
        s = a.s;
        a.s = 0;
        a.p = nullptr;
        std::cout << "move = overload was called";
        return *this;
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
            std::cout << p[i];
    }
    
    ~foo() {
        std::cout << std::endl << "foo destructor" << s << std::endl;
    }
};

foo foo_test() {
    foo in{10};
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    foo my{ 5 };
    my.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    my = foo_test();
    my.print();
}
```

## Output

```
01234
move cons was called

foo destructor0
move = overload was called
foo destructor0
0123456789
foo destructor10
```

Comment: You likely have copy elision disabled. Otherwise, a different output is observed: https://godbolt.org/z/ajch3W3f5. What is your build setup?

Comment: Visual studio 2019, ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence or absence of move operators makes no difference, whatsoever, on how constructors and destructors work. Each object is constructed, and at some point gets destroyed, via its destructor. This is fundamental to C++. Move semantics doesn't change that. This is the first important thing to understand.

A move constructor is just another constructor, and counts as a constructor. The move assignment operator is completely irrelevant. The moved-from object must still be, at some point, get destroyed. The moved-to object was previously constructed. Both of these objects, at some point, will get constructed and destroyed.

```
foo foo_test() {
    foo in{10};
    return in;
}
```

But here you introduce another factor: copy elision. Here, since C++11, the compiler is allowed (but not required) to completely [elide the copy when returning `in`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) from `foo_test()`.

Normally `return`ing any object from a function performs an implicit copy (or move). But here, depending on your compiler's whim, no copy or move will occur. The `in` object effectively gets constructed in the caller's context, and the `return` is a nothing-burger. It doesn't really "return" anything. In the caller's context, once returned it already has a fully baked object, in its place. However, here:

```
my = foo_test();
```

because the returned value gets assigned to an existing object, at some point its assignment or move operator will have to be invoked. The object constructed in `foo_test`, then, gets destroyed (whether or not its implicit copy, as a result of the `return`, was elided).

So, the answer to your question: what happens here is ... it depends. It depends on what your compiler decides to do.

And it is not important to understand what exactly happens here. What is important, is to understand that:

1. In C++ every object gets constructed and destroyed.
2. The presence or absence of move operators does not change that. After the object gets constructed or destroyed it may get moved-to, or moved-from, but it doesn't affect its construction or destruction.
3. An object move constructor counts as a constructor, for the first two rules.
4. C++ has optional or mandatory copy elision, depending on the C++ version. All that copy elision does is effectively make the copy go away. It still doesn't change the rule that all objects are constructed and destroyed.
5. All that copy elision might do is "collapse" two objects into one object, when the implicit copy as a result of `return`ing from a function occurs. This is the farthest that the first two rules can be bent. Effectively the two objects, in the called, and the caller's context, become one object, that follow the same rules, otherwise.